# Stop Redirecting to and from www

Tags: redirect

I've got a situation where I don't want www to redirect to the domain, or the domain to redirect to www.

I looked around and found

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

I added this to my functions file, but the site still redirects. I don't understand it enough to do anything about it.

My site is running nginx, and I thought maybe it was related to the config file there, but I didn't see anything.

Anywhere else I can look to fix this?
Thanks
Rich

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question. Are you trying to have your website show only `example.com` and not `www.example.com`? Please elaborate more so we better understand your situation and provide a quick solution.

Comment: If a user requests example.com, it I don't want it to redirect to www.example.com. Also, if a user requests www.example.com I don't want it to redirect to example.com.

Comment: What is your WordPress site set up using? The www or non-www?

Comment: The site is setup with site.com.
One thing I cannot tell if its WordPress of if its Nginx doing the redirecting. In the Nginx config, I don't see anything for www or redirect.

Comment: I see. This would be on the hosting side then, look at your DNS settings for your domain and you will see that the `www` will be pointing to the same IP as your non-www.